# How to download HTML pages with the correct encoding using C#?

Tags: c#, encoding, screen-scraping

I needed a method that gets a link to a page and returns the title of this page.

I used WebClient -

```
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        var htmlString = webClient.DownloadString(_link);
```

It works well, but it fails with encoding of foreign languages. I'm getting question marks and weird characters instead of the text I need.

Is there a generic way to identify the encoding of the page and use it? I need it to support most of the encodings if not all.

Comment: Does the web page and/or server specify which encoding it was encoded in?

Comment: The web page can be any web page on the internet, that's the problem :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) you can do something like this

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
using (var read = client.OpenRead("http://your.com"))
{
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load(read, true); // true = get encoding from byte order masks
    // process doc, extract title
    var title = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//title").InnerText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

...

    public static void GetFile
            (
            string strURL,
            string strFilePath
            )
        {

            WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(strURL); 

            WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse(); 

            Stream ReceiveStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

            Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");

            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader( ReceiveStream, encode );

            string strResponse=readStream.ReadToEnd();

            StreamWriter oSw=new StreamWriter(strFilePath);

            oSw.WriteLine(strResponse);

            oSw.Close();

            readStream.Close();

            myWebResponse.Close();

        }
```

Comment: This obviously only works, if the page is indeed in UTF-8! Additionally, it doesn't decode html characters like &uuml;